# Restrict type parameter by means of generics

Tags: java, generics

## Given Calorie interface and implemented classes

```
// Interface that defines that item has calories and may be compared by it

interface Calorie extends Comparable<Calorie> {
  public int compareTo(Calorie object);
  public int getCalories();
}

// Examples of classes CaloryGrader is supposed to work with
class Drink implements Calorie {
    // Some implemenation...
}

class Bakery implements Calorie {
    // Some implementation...
}

class Cake extends Bakery {
    // Some implementation...
}
```

```
## Given CaloryGrader class where I need to implement sorted static "grade" method ##

class CaloryGrader {

    /**
     * Returns sorted in ascending order copy of items list.
     * 
     * Sort order is defined by item calories.
     *
     * @param items collection of items to sort
     * @return sorted copy
     */

    public List grade(List items) {
        // Add implementation
    }

}
```

The task is - to write grade by means of generics in order for it to sort only List of items which include Calories and its sublclasses.

I have written the following signature of grade method

```
  public static <T extends Calorie> List<T> grade(List<T> items) {
```

Still, it does not work and I cannot figure out why.

**T** is a type of item which method can accept
**List** is a return type of a method

I assumed that argument **List** will restrict the List which can be passed to the method by only to all subclasses of Calories. But it is not correct right now.

I can create a list of **raw type** and pass it to the method. I assume it is due to the fact that it converts to List and it fits.

The resolution should be not to pass raw types to the method and receive a compile-time error. I guess I miss something.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a `List<Calorie>` parameter instead ? It will be able to hold every implementation of the interface. Since `Calorie` is a `Comparable`, you can sort it from there. No need to have the specific instance type so there is no need for a generic type from what I understand

Comment: @AxelH yeap, but how I can be sure in this case that the list will not hold raw types at the compile time?
Applying List<Calorie> I will be able to pass to the method List calorie = new Arraylist<>();

Comment: You cannot forbid raw types. The compiler only issues a warning when you use raw types, and that's it. You can always pass raw types to generic methods.

Comment: @Sweeper you are right, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Array for this hard constraint: grade(T[] items)

On top of that, an array backed List for quick conversion back & forth.